# Trying to refactor this code to use only immutable structures

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, immutability, ramda.js

I'm a student of functional programming. I am still weaning myself off the old variable-mutation habits. But sometimes I get stuck. Ok, so here is the question--suppose we have the following closure

```
const bookShelf = () => {
  let books = []
  const listBooks = () => books
  const addBook = (book) => {
    books = books.concat(book)
    return function removeBook() { books = books.filter( b => b !== book ) }
  }
  return {addBook,listBooks}
}

const { addBook, listBooks } = bookShelf()
const removeMobyDick = addBook('Moby Dick')
const removeWalden = addBook('Walden')
removeWalden()
console.log(listBooks()) // ["Moby Dick"]
```

Note that I have one object which is mutated: books.

My question is, how can I refactor this code so that books is immutable yet I achieve the same end-result. Feel free to use a functional library like Ramda if need be. My naive thought here is somehow use recursion to pass in a new value of books and then pass that version back. Seems a bit overreach so I thought to seek out help from someone more knowledgable in this arena.

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: First I would split `addBook` and `removeBook` to 2 functions. I think it's bad design because to remove a book, you must have a reference to the function to remove it. What If I want to remove N books, so I must N references to the `removeBook` function.

Comment: And for `addBook`, returns a new array containing the book added. And same for `removeBook`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just leave `book` constant in your `bookshelf`. That will require creating a new `bookshelf` every time of course, so the easiest approach is to make `books` be a parameter of the function:

```
function bookShelf(books) {
  return {
    listBooks() { return books },
    addBook(book) { return bookShelf(books.concat([book])); }
  }
}

const empty = bookShelf([]);
const shelfWithMobyDick = empty.addBook('Moby Dick');
const shelfWithMobyDickAndWalden = shelfWithMobyDick.addBook('Walden');
console.log(shelfWithMobyDick.listBooks());
```

As you can see, there's no need for a `removeBook` function - you just use the old value that had not yet included the book.

If you want to be able to remove the book you just added from an arbitrary bookshelf, you can also return both the new bookshelf and a remover function:

```
    …,
    addBook(book) {
      return {
        bookShelf: bookShelf(books.concat([book]));
        removeThis(shelf) { return bookShelf(shelf.listBooks().filter(b => b !== book)); }
      };
    }
```

to be used as

```
const empty = bookShelf([]);
const {bookShelf: shelfWithMobyDick, removeThis: removeMobyDick} = empty.addBook('Moby Dick');
const {bookShelf: shelfWithMobyDickAndWalden, removeThis: removeWalden} = shelfWithMobyDick.addBook('Walden');
const shelfWithWalden = removeMobyDick(shelfWithMobyDickAndWalden);
console.log(shelfWithWalden.listBooks());
```

Comment: Okay but how do I Moby Dick and keep Walden? I mean if I have 50 books added this way and want to remove book number 25, with the above method I can just removeBook25() and still have books 1-24 and 26-50.

Comment: @Babak See the edit. Creating the `removeThis` function inside `addBook` is really ugly though (it's not just the variable names in my example :-D), you'd better add a `removeBook` method to every bookshelf object that takes the book to remove as an argument.

Comment: Interesting, I have to study this. I'm curious, if I added a removeBook method to the bookshelf itself, ie, { listBooks: ..., addBook: ..., removeBook: } how would removeBook work in that scenario?

Comment: @Babak You'd call `const shelfWithWalden = shelfWithMobyDickAndWalden.removeBook('Moby Dick');`

Comment: So that would return a copy of that bookshelf without that book though there are many other copies of the bookshelf out there... I get it. Thing is, I modeled this example from an old version of Redux github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/v1.0.0/src/createStore.js#L42 where books = listeners. Though even the current version of Redux still uses this mutable way. I can see why, because they callback functions called after the reducer are kept private to the createStore function; however, I'm wonder if they couldn't have done it in an immutable way.

Comment: @Babak I don't know their design decisions, but most likely because copying arrays around is costly and they are sure that the state is linear (never branches, gets cloned etc).

Answer (score 1):

The bookshelf type doesn’t really seem to be accomplishing anything here, so let’s just make it a list (array).

```
let bookshelf = [];
```

Now it looks like you want a way to produce a list with a new item and a way of removing that item from the list. A little weird, but you can do that by returning both in a tuple (array):

```js
const remove = (list, value) =>
    list.filter(x => x !== value);

const addRemovable = (list, value) =>
    [[...list, value], list => remove(list, value)];


let bookshelf = [];
let removeMobyDick;
let removeWalden;

[bookshelf, removeMobyDick] = addRemovable(bookshelf, 'Moby Dick');
[bookshelf, removeWalden] = addRemovable(bookshelf, 'Walden');

bookshelf = removeWalden(bookshelf);

console.log(bookshelf);
```

This doesn’t look nice and you probably wouldn’t want to write something like it, but it does achieve the same thing as your original.

Comment: My bookshelf system is a simplified version of how Redux's createStore works. books = listeners see link: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/v1.0.0/src/createStore.js#L42

Comment: I'm trying to understand why (even in the current version) they don't re-write this createStore function with better functional programming practices.

Comment: @Babak: JavaScript isn’t a language designed around pure functional programming. If mutation is nicely contained, it’s not really a problem, and can make reading and implementation much simpler.

Comment: @Babak: though it’s not as if Redux and change listeners are shining examples of good design. The whole concept of adding a listener is pretty non-functional.